# why does my ajax function not see the variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to JQuery, the below function works great when I hard code the 'value' into the ajax url. However when I use the var 'value' the ajax call fails. 'Value' is not coming through in the function. Nevertheless it is in the global scope.  So why does value not work? I have tried with and without quotes.

Many thanks !

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".product_id").blur(function() {

    var value = $(".product_id").val()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'product_prices/' + 'value' ,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data)
        }


    });

});
});
```

Comment: url: 'product_prices/' + 'value' , you are adding the string 'value' not the variable value. Remove the quotations

Comment: it should be without quotes. are you sure you have the right value there? try alert(value) or console.log(value) to check.

Comment: You have to work on developing the ability to see trivial errors.  Its pretty obvious above that you have added the word "value" instead of the actual value.

Comment: @jk yup agreed. I am a server guy where I find the syntax infinitely more obvious and the debug tool far better. For me JS with all it's nested functions is a nightmare of a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following statement:

```
url: 'product_prices/' + 'value' ,
```

you're currently invoking an url of the form `product_prices/value`, while you want something like `product_prices/nnn`, where "nnn" is the current value.

So change the statement into:

```
url: 'product_prices/' + value ,
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works ! I will award the point to you as you got there first plus you gave me some comments of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".product_id").blur(function() {

    var value = $(".product_id").val()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "product_prices/" + value ,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data)
        }


    });

});
});
```